# IntelliJ IDEA - Getter And Setters Template - JavaFX Observable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter

I've created a Getter template for IntelliJ IDEA with the following code:

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
is##
#else
get##
#end
${name}() {
#if (!$field.primitive && !$field.isModifierFinal())
    if($field.name == null)
        $field.name = new ${field.type}();
#end
    return $field.name;
}
```

Which creates something like:

```
public String getString(){
    if(mString == null)
        mString = new String();
    return mString;
}
```

But when working in JavaFX with `Property<T>` it doesn't work, it seems that no matter the getter template it will always return

```
public StringProperty stringProperty(){
    return stringProperty;
}
```

Any idea on how to change that default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for properties at the moment, please vote for [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151227).